# Set CSS height property to truncate large divisions

Tags: javascript, html, css

**Never let a C programmer meddle in CSS/web-design.*

that being said, I have a task that I cannot solve for a simple forum (SMF) i host.

**Goal**

Set a div's CSS such that it will truncate the area past a certain height.

**Example 1:**

Someone on forum posts a 1 line code snippet in their response.

- this div of 1 line should show as 1 line

**Example 2:**

Someone on forum posts a 500 line code snippet in their response (e-gads!)

- this div of 500 lines should only display as 50 lines, with scroll/resize visible.
- this div can also be resized by user to 500 lines

**Notes**

1. It appears I want the exact-opposite of 'height:fit-content', which sets to the *larger of* intrinsic min-height, and avail-height ([height - CSS | MSDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/height)
2. I've tried muddling around with *height, min-height, max-height*, but none satisfies the Goal.
3. max-height is cool, but it caps the max size you can resize to max-height!

**Reference Code (from SMF's Themes/default/css/index.css)**

```
/* A code block - maybe PHP ;). */
code.bbc_code
{
    display: block;
    font-family: "dejavu sans mono", "monaco", "lucida console", "courier new", monospace;
    font-size: small;
    background: #fff;
    border-top: 2px solid #999;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #999;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    padding: 3px 1em;
    overflow: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;

    /* (edit) this is the best i could do. but has exact opposite effect! */
    min-height : 1em;
    height: fit-content; 
    resize: vertical;

}
```

*this ref code will show a '1-liner' as 1-line with scroll/resize & a '500-liner as 500-lines with scroll/resize. how do you make it show the 500-liner as 50?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is `max-height: 50em;` and `height: auto;`.

[See JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/KittMedia/STb7f/)

Answer (score 0):

You should check **[this](http://css-tricks.com/line-clampin/)** out.  This code will basically truncate based on the number of lines specified.